# Rails API authentication without requiring login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, redux, jwt

I have a site where I have lists of generic items. I am fetching these lists on my front-end via axios requests to my rails API. (I am fetching in Redux actions)

I'm using Active Model Serializer and so the JSON format of my data can be gathered simply by visiting the url "http://localhost:3000/items" (the JSON is automatically set to render via my controller)

I want to restrict access to the API, but still display these lists of items on my site for all users regardless of whether or not they are logged in.

Is there a way to protect this data without requiring a login while still fetching it on the front end?

Answer (score 3):

You can guard the API with an authentication token (using `before_action` in rails), and include this token in your frontend code when sending requests to the API.

Axios example

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/items',
  headers: { 'Authorization': '<insert token here>' }
});
```

This means a user will now have to read your frontend code to find the token in order to access the API directly, which protects your API to some extent, especially if your frontend code is minified.

Comment: This was very helpful in leading me to the right search keywords.  I ended up using information from this article: https://www.joshqn.com/rails-api-token-authentication/  Thank you.